# How to move a DocumentFile With API 22?

Tags: android

To access files on the SD card with write permission i'm forced to use the [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html) interface, which has no relation with the java File interface nor offers a method to move the file.

There's a helper static class [DocumentsContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html) that offers a [moveDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#moveDocument(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri)) method starting from API 24 (Nougat), but nothing below.

Copying and deleting the DocumentFile is a bad idea, as it takes time.
Any suggestion?

Comment: you can use File and the canWrite() method of it. It will be easier for you

Comment: @Dipalishah on Lollipop you can use File for read access, but write ops will fail.